# system command returns strange value

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I have this script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 npid=$(pgrep -f procname | wc -l)
 echo $npid
 if [ $npid -lt 3 ];then
  service procname start;
 fi
```

When `procname` is running, it works fine showing the correct number for `$npid`. It fails when there isn't any `procname` running. It should return zero, but it returns `npid=3`, exactly 3. The same problem I see for `ps auxw | grep procname | grep -v grep | wc -l` as well.

Something trivially wrong I just couldn't figure out, any suggestions ?

*** EDIT

```
# This returns nothing if therisn't a process name poopit running
pgrep -f poopit 


# In the case when no process running, below returns zero if typed on a bash cmd line 
pgrep -f poopit | wc -l 

# If running,
pgrep -f poopit | wc -l
17 
# If running, the script $npid shows 
19
```

Comment: If `procname` isn't running, what does `pgrep -f procname` return (by itself)? What platform?

Comment: debian, it returns nothing

Comment: on my Fedora that works

Comment: Can you update showing the output of `pgrep -f procname` in both cases?

Comment: When there is no `procname` running `pgrep -f procname` returns an empty output and then `wc -l` returns 0.
When there are processes `pgrep -f procname` returns their pids ad `wc -l` counts them

Comment: To rule out shell functions or aliases of the same name eclipsing the underlying utilities, invoke them with full paths: `/usr/bin/pgrep` and `/usr/bin/wc`.

Comment: This is what happens when you use `-f`. If you're adding it out of habit, don't. If you're adding it out of necessity, narrow your pattern.